# Sniff HTTP Requests from TV

Tags: streaming, wireshark

I'm trying to find a solution to sniff get requests of Smart TV when in request video from the service server. I'm trying to get m3u8 playlist.

My current setup is mac + tv (wifi) and router Asus with merlin firmware.

Does someone know how to find that request? Just interested on URL requests, not pockets.

Comment: You may find it difficult to get the URL if https is in used. You can probably find the address by sniffing UDP (and maybe TCP) port 53 for the TV when requesting the URL, and tcpdump will likely show you the DNS queries in a fairly readable form.  If communication is happening in http that can be sniffed, but if its https you may struggle to intercept the traffic unless you can set up a proxy server (or add your own ca to the TV, but even then its going to be non-trivial)

Comment: Do you mean DNS server, which will hold the traffic?

Comment: (Usually but not always) you can sniff DNS traffic on the router. You can sniff for traffic entering the router on the man interface and see traffic destined for the DNS server on the router and also DNS traffic going through the router if an external name server is used.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to see the traffic. For this, you have to either:

1. Gain MitM position by routing the traffic through your PC.
2. Be able to monitor the traffic, e.g.

   - Using a switch with a monitoring / mirroring port that sends copy of everything to you. As this is a home network, you probably don't have one, but any old ethernet hub without the switching capabilities will work as well, if you happen to find one.
   - Capturing the WiFi packets. Typically WiFi adapters are only interested in 802.11 frames that matches itself as destination and disregards everything else, so you may need a special driver that allows sniffing.

You also have to be sure the TV is using plain HTTP: you won't get the URLs out of HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Which method is the easiest? Traffic is in HTTPS, I was able to sniff by redirecting with my router to my mac by using iptables. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You are getting deep into device specific territory if you are trying to handle https. What make and model is your TV? There is (a very small) chance someone will be able to shine light on how to change its settings to allow you to hack this - assuming its even possible.

Comment: Someone buy me a Samsung SmartTV and I'll try and hack it. ;)

Comment: Can you set a proxy server in the router or add a root cert to it?  Does it check the cert for https pages? ( if not, or if it allows you to override the cert warning you can use iptables to redirect traffic to a web server you control, then look at the server log.